# How to Spread formwidgets in doctrine into multiple columns?

Tags: forms, symfony1

I'm using symfony1.4 with doctrine. I'm able to insert/update/delete records using form widgets. But the problem is i have some 75 fields in a single form which i want to spread into two columns.Please tell me a way to implement this please.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by rendering each one individually on your template or view... For example, if your form has a widget called **name**, in your template of partial, you can render it by doing:

```
//this will render the row as the assigned formater does
<?php echo $form['name']->renderRow()?>
```

or

```
//in a table
<tr>
  <td>
    <!-- will output only the label -->
    <?php echo $form['name']->renderLabel()?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <!-- will output only the 'input' -->
    <?php echo $form['name']->render()?>
    <!-- will output only the error messages -->
    <?php echo $form['name']->renderError()?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you have any doubt check the [Symfony's Forms for Web Designers](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/03-Forms-for-web-Designers) for more details.

Comment: thankyou, Is there anyother way of doing this because i have 75 fileds, and i ordered in the way i wanted inside form class using movefiled, so now i want to display first 40 fields in one <td> and the remaining in other </td>.